# In SKLearn Logistic Regression, class = Balanced helps run the model with imbalanced data? what methodology does this option use

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, logistic-regression, sampling

Having read about random under sampling, random over sampling and **SMOTE**, I am trying to understand what methodology is used by the default implement in SKlearn package for Logistic Regression or Random Forest. 
I have checked documentation [**here**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

> The **balanced** mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as **n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))**

I am not able to understand of it under samples majority class or over samples minority class to create the balanced set

Comment: This blog provides good information relevant to the OP. https://towardsdatascience.com/practical-tips-for-class-imbalance-in-binary-classification-6ee29bcdb8a7
 As per this,  when one uses class_weights, instead of usual cross entropy, it uses weigted cross entropy for loss function.
weightedCrossEntropy = −w1*ylog(p) − w2*(1−y)log(1−p)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are very different.

SMOTE will alter the data and make the dataset balanced by oversampling  (means it will generate similar looking data as in minority class to increase its samples. So the ***new*** dataset is created.

In LR, it doesnt make the dataset balanced. It doesn't create new data. It just penalizes the mis-classification of minority class more. So the model will be careful enough to take care of that class. Thats why its called `'class_weight'`.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation for numpy.bincount states each bin gives the number of occurrences of its index value in x (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). Therefore, since in the expression used by sklearn bincounts is in the denominator, classes that have high frequencies receive low weights and classes with low frequencies receive high weights. Let us see this in action:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'classes': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3]})

n_samples = df.shape[0]
classes = df['classes'].unique()
bins = np.bincount(df['classes'])
n_classes = bins.shape[0]

weights = n_samples/(n_classes*bins)

sns.barplot(classes, weights)
plt.xlabel('class label')
plt.ylabel('weight')
plt.show()
```

[image]